# Bind Color Preview Squares in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I'm trying to make a `ComboBox` with text items and a colored box next to each.

I want to bind an `Array` of colors to a `ComboBox.ItemTemplate` `Border` `Background`.

- [red] Apple
- [green] Pear
- [purple] Grape

I made this example in Photoshop:

[image: Color Combobox]

---

**Problem**

However the Background Colors are not showing up.

It could be a `List` instead of an `Array`, but I don't know what color method to use, `Color`, `Colors`, `Brush`, `Brushes`, `SolidColorBrush`, `String` and how to get it to bind and display properly.

I got the idea from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/51096379/6806643
But this Binds to the Text Color Name in the ComboBox. If the word is not a color it will display empty.

---

**C#**

```
public static SolidColorBrush[] _cboColor_Previews = new SolidColorBrush[] {
    new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),
    new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green),
    new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Purple),
};
public static SolidColorBrush[] cboColor_Previews
{
    get { return _cboColor_Previews; }
    set { _cboColor_Previews = value; }
}
```

**XAML**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboColors" 
          HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="0,2,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Width="100"
          Height="22" >

    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Background="{Binding cboColor_Previews}" 
                        Height="12" 
                        Width="12" 
                        Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" 
                           Margin="5,0" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>

    <System:String>Apple</System:String>
    <System:String>Pear</System:String>
    <System:String>Grape</System:String>
</ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need to define brushes.

I'd define a class to represent your fruits like so:

```
public class Fruits
{
    public string Fruit { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
    public string ColorStr { get { return Color.ToString(); } }
    public Fruits(string fruit, Color color)
    {
        Fruit = fruit;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

The `Color` class is the `System.Windows.Media.Color` class. When you do binding in `XAML`, binding to a `Hex` string that represents the color works, and `Color.ToString()` does just that.

So now I'd have a list of your `Fruits` class:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public List<Fruits> FruitList { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        FruitList = new List<Fruits>()
        {
            new Fruits("Apple", Colors.Red),
            new Fruits("Pear", Colors.Green),
            new Fruits("Grape", Colors.Purple)
        };

        cboColors.ItemsSource = FruitList;
    }
}
```

Set `ComboBox.ItemsSource` to our list as seen above.

And your `ComboBox` bindings should look like this:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cboColors" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,20,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" Height="22">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border Background="{Binding ColorStr}" Height="12" Width="12" Margin="2"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Fruit}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

### Final Output:

[image]

---

### EDIT

Getting the selected item. At this point, your `ComboBox.ItemsSource` is *bound* to your `FruitList` list. Therefore, whenever the user selects an item from the drop-down, an object of type `Fruist` is being selected.

Therefore, if you want to get the item selected, you can for instance use the `ComboBox_SelectionChanged` event, and cast the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` into type `Fruits`.

```
private void CboColors_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Casting the selected item to type Fruits
    var selected = (Fruits)cboColors.SelectedItem;
    // Here I'm setting window title to the selected fruit to illustrate.
    // You can use this however you like.
    this.Title = selected.Fruit;
}
```

I think it would be a good idea for you to dive into the world of `DataBinding` and learn the basics.
[This](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_data_binding.htm) and [this](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/data-binding/introduction/) could be a good starting point.

Comment: It's working, though I'm having one problem. If I try to use `cboColors.SelectedItem == "Apple"` it gives error `Unable to cast object of type 'Fruits' to type 'System.String'.` How can I use `SelectedItem`?

Comment: @MattMcManis please see the edited answer. I also think it would be a good idea for you to learn `DataBinding` as it's an integral part of `WPF`. I've linked to helpful resources.

Comment: It's working great. I'm going to test it out a little more and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Is there a way I can use a `public` `List` `get` `set` instead of `cboColors.ItemsSource = FruitList;` to bind the items to the combobox? So I don't have to put it in the `MainWindow`?

Comment: That's an entirely different question, and I'm not sure if I understand you either. You should ask a new question for that.